# Nano in a while loop

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, nano

I currently having a problem in which I am trying to read read/monitor the content of a list of files which is stored in text file.

Problem with my current approach is that leads to all the files being opened in nano, rather than giving me the option, whether I want to delete the entry or not.. (last part not implemented yet..)

The text file is stored like this

```
Aline
Bline
Cline
Dline
Eline
```

What I am currently doing is:

```
cat file |  while read line; do nano "$line"; done
```

which rather opening one file at time, opens all the files at the same time.

Solution?

Comment: That command is syntactically incorrect, please post the actual command/script you're using.

Comment: @muru not sure what you mean.. it works here?

Comment: you need another semicolon, or the shell is going to wait for `done`

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? Why would you want to open single lines in nano? Do you need to edit them? If so, what should happen with the edited lines? If not, there's no need to use nano to just view them.

Comment: That still doesn't show the behaviour described (`nano` complains about stdin and the whole thing just fails.)

Comment: @ByteCommander presumably each line of the file is the name of a file...

Comment: I wont be able to make a pattern, to check, which is why i need to view them manualy (not edit).. I used nano in my example, as I am used to using that.. 
but other could be used as aswell. As @Zanna mentioned, yes each line is the name of the file.

Comment: So you want to view each file yourself, close it, then have the next file be opened when you are done?

Comment: yes.. Presumably with an option to delete the entry, if the file passes the "manual test"

Comment: hmm so having the user be able to delete the line while running the would be a nice to have... I see

Comment: @Zanna not quite, I will close nano, and then decide whether the line should be deleted or not..   I amcurrently not able to view the file one at the time.. It just loops all files in nano..

Comment: I think you want to delete the line from the file, not the file itself - is that right?

Comment: @Zanna yes you are right..

Answer (score 1):

[`zenity`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zenity.1.html) is a handy tool for quick dialog boxes:

```
keep=()
while read -r filename; do
    zenity --text-info --title="$filename" --filename="$filename" \
           --ok-label=Keep --cancel-label=Remove
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        keep+=("$filename")
    fi
done < file_of_filenames
printf "%s\n" "${keep[@]}" > file_of_filenames
```